# Get value from hidden inputs

Tags: php, mysql, forms, input, hidden

I have these hiiden fields for each product. I can get the hidden fiels with jquery. But when I enter data it doesnt go to database, I shows always 0.  I thinit is because of the same named values. how can I solve this problem without changing the input names!

I have also one table on my database for all products.

```
<select id="mySelect" onchange="npup.doSelect(this);" name="catagory" type="text">
        <option value="">choice</option> 
        <option value="curtain_fabrics">Curtain Fabrics</option>
        <option value="curtain">Curtains</option>
        <option value="curtain_holder">Curtain Holders</option>
    </select>
    <div id="mySpecialElements">
          <div id="npupcurtain_fabrics" class="hidden">
           <div class="fe" >Quality: <input type="text" name="quality">  </div>
           <div class="fe" >Width:<input type="text" name="width"> </div>
           <div class="fe" >Price:<input type="text" name="price"> $/m</div>
        </div>

       <div id="npupcurtain" class="hidden">
           <div class="fe" >Quality<input type="text" name="quality"></div>
           <div class="fe" >Width:<input type="text" name="width"> </div>
           <div class="fe" >Height:<input type="text" name="height"></div>
           <div class="fe" >Price:<input type="text"  name="price" >$/set</div>
       </div>

       <div id="npupcurtain_holder" class="hidden">
           <div class="fe" >Material<input type="text" name="material"></div>
           <div class="fe" >Moldel:<input type="text" name="model"> </div>
           <div class="fe" >Price:<input type="text"  name="price" >$/piece</div>
        </div>
```

Here is mysql code:

```
  $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO products (name, catagory, quality, width,  height,  price, date_add)
VALUES('$product_name','$product_category','$prosuct_quality','$produt_width','$product_height','$product_price', now())");
```

Comment: and how exactly u are getting those values ??

Comment: We need to see the server-side code where you're attempting to retrieve your values

Comment: What about using arrays?

Comment: I think it goes throgh all fields and because there are some named inputs it returnes 0... I need a solution for this only

Comment: You should use different names for different inputs. If you have two inputs with `name="price"`, only one will be sent to the server. In most browsers it'll be the last one, but you can't rely on that.

Comment: @Arjan:  You r so right. I just to use same form for my different products. maybe I have to make different form for each category?

Comment: Does anyone know any solution that checks all fields to find the entered value to send to the db?

Answer (score 2):

You can send them to the server as arrays:

```
 <div id="npupcurtain_fabrics" class="hidden">
           <div class="fe" >Quality: <input type="text" name="fabrics[quality]">  </div>
           <div class="fe" >Width:<input type="text" name="fabrics[width]"> </div>
           <div class="fe" >Price:<input type="text" name="fabrics[price]"> $/m</div>
        </div>

       <div id="npupcurtain" class="hidden">
           <div class="fe" >Quality<input type="text" name="npupcurtain[quality]"></div>
           <div class="fe" >Width:<input type="text" name="npupcurtain[width]"> </div>
           <div class="fe" >Height:<input type="text" name="npupcurtain[height]"></div>
           <div class="fe" >Price:<input type="text"  name="npupcurtain[price]" >$/set</div>
       </div>

       <div id="npupcurtain_holder" class="hidden">
           <div class="fe" >Material<input type="text" name="holder[material]"></div>
           <div class="fe" >Moldel:<input type="text" name="holder[model]"> </div>
           <div class="fe" >Price:<input type="text"  name="holder[price]" >$/piece</div>
        </div>
```

In the server-side..say `PHP` the variables would be like:

```
$_POST['fabrics']['quality'];
$_POST['holder']['model'];
....
```

Comment: I have at least 10 options in the category, so should I do for each variable own POST-submmision? it will be at leat 80 post command like 
$_POST['fabrics']['quality'];
$_POST['curtai']['quality'];
$_POST['pelmet']['quality'];

and I think I have make a new db table with large number of rows!

Answer (score 0):

After seeing the comments, I think the problem is with your SQL only, not the other parts. You might not do the concatenation and building query correctly. Try the following code. (I need to mention that it is not recommended to concatenate the string like this. Use placeholder `?` to prevent SQL injection).

```
    $sql = mysql_query(
    "INSERT INTO products (
                      name, 
                      catagory, 
                      quality, 
                      width,  
                      height,  
                      price, 
                      date_add)
    VALUES(
          '".$product_name."'
        ,'".$product_category."'
        ,'".$prosuct_quality."'
        ,'".$produt_width."'
        ,'".$product_height."'
        ,'".$product_price."'
        , now())");
```

For placeholders(prepared statements), see http://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

Comment: No, I have select input for the category and it returns other hidden fields related to the produt using jquery. And I try to send values from these displayed fields to the database, and I think the same named inputs are the most problems

Comment: thank you for your help, but it still doesnt work...
It sends 0 for those fields that have the same named inputs?

Comment: Can you use a web developer tool (like firebug console in FireFox) and examine the post request sent, and see if submitted post request is sending `0` or the form is sending correct values and at the backend they become `0`?

Comment: I know why it does that...Ii always sends the last input's (the same names) to the db.  Is there any solution to validate the form so, that it checks all fields with the same input name, and take that one that value has been entered??

Answer (score 0):

This can be as a result of a ***wrong data type*** for the column of the table in the database. E.g. you are inserting a `string` into a column in the database table that accepts only `integers`, hence you get the value `0` stored.

Answer (score -1):

use id tag vs name tag in your html

Example change

`<div class="fe" >Quality: <input type="text" name="quality">  </div>`

to

`<div class="fe" >Quality: <input type="text" id="quality">  </div>`

Comment: Okay, but what does this mean and why does it matter?

Comment: uhm, for POST submissions, you need a `name` field, or the server wouldn't find these in the request ...

Comment: @ KarelG .  I have name filed, the name goes to the database, the only problem is the same named fields like with, height and quality